# Reference a temporary in msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does this compile on MS Visual C++?

```
struct myClass{};

void func(myClass& arg){}

void main() {
   func( myClass() );  // works even though func only takes myClass& 
}                      // (not const myClass&!!)
```

Does this work on other compilers as well or is this MSVC specific (or even a compiler bug?). I can even get the reference on this rvalue like this:

```
void func(myClass* arg){}

int main() {
    func( &myClass() ); 
}
```

This works ONLY on Objects that are temporarily created with a constructor. This wouldn't work with any other rvalue like (myClass() + myClass()) for example..

Comment: This is the most evil extension of them all imo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It compiles because MSVC has a non-standard compliant  "extension" that allows binding non-const references to temporaries.

The first example should not compile on a standards compliant compiler.

In the second example, you are taking the address of a temporary to set the value of a pointer. This should also result in an error.

Clang 3.2 produces:

> error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'Foo' [-Waddress-of-temporary]

while GCC 4.7.3 produces

> error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

Comment: "*you are taking the address of a temporary to set the value of a pointer. This is allowed*" Is it? I don't think so. 5.3.1[expr.unary.op]/3: *The operand shall be an lvalue or a quialified-id*, but a temporary is neither of them. It should be rejected by the compiler.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas good point, thanks. I was fooled by an old version of GCC.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC 2017 with default project settings (that now include `/permissive-` flag) [yields an error](https://godbolt.org/z/fMy3XL):

> error C2664: 'void func(myClass &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'myClass' to 'myClass &'
>   note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue

Even if `/permissive-` option is not viable for some reason using `/W4` will yield a warning:

> warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from 'myClass' to 'myClass &'
>   note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue