# auto reference to Eigen block not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I want to use an auto reference to a block of an eigen matrix:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
void foo(MatrixXf& a)
{
    auto& a_block = a.block(2, 3, 4, 5);
    a_block = MatrixXf::Random(4,5);
}
```

This does not compile with GCC, since `a.block(2, 3, 4, 5)` is evaluated into a temporary, while `a.block(2, 3, 4, 5) = MatrixXf::Random(4,5);` works perfectly.

From my point of view this is not expected behaviour. Is there an elegant fix to this problem? Should this be considered a bug / feature request to Eigen?

EDIT:

using `auto` instead of `auto&` solves the problem!

The question has been marked as a duplicate of [Reference a temporary in msvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570661/reference-a-temporary-in-msvc), but it has nothing to do with MSVC. I also made clear that it's obvious that `a.block(2, 3, 4, 5)` is evaluated into a temporary. The question was about whether this is correct behaviour of Eigen.

Comment: *"From my point of view this is not expected behaviour."* As [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570661/reference-a-temporary-in-msvc) explains, GCC is correct to reject the code. *"Is there an elegant fix"* I don't know much about Eigen, but can't you simply do `auto a_block = ...;`?

Comment: right, `auto a_block = ...;` should solve the problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or you can use an lvalue `auto&&` reference, or `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`block` doesn't actually return a reference, but instead it creates a reference-like object of type [`Block`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Block.html).  A freshly created rvalue of any type can't be assigned to a non-`const` lvalue reference, so this is all expected behavior.

Assigning to a `Block` rvalue is fine because it has an overloaded `operator=` (which unfortunately doesn't get its own entry in the documentation page because it looks like they generate the `=` definition using a macro).  That `=` function then sends all your data to the relevant parts of the `Matrix` that the `Block` was created from.